# Prebuild libjingle library for Android

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

Is there anybody can tell me where to get prebuild libjingle library for Android?

I wrote an libjingle app on Android to make video calls between web app and android app. (Here is the [project](https://github.com/wennycooper/webrtcClient))

Most function works fine, but the microphone seems not work on my HTC Butterfly S phone. (It did work on ACER E600 phone of my friend).

The library binary is from some other project several months ago, which is kind of old I think.

I tried to build the latest libjingle library but the build environment and process is too complicated to me.

Anyone comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just build the latest libjingle library library.
Furthermore, the app with the latest lib fixed the microphone phone!!

Comment: hello please can you guide how to build the libjingle ?
i tried this demo app https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo
but when i try to connect on my Link i get an exception "SDP content error"
i don't know if the library is issue, but i want to see if i can have a new build